# String replace in a file by using batch file. gettting error : < was unexpected at this time batcch file

Tags: string, file, batch-file, replace

Could anyone please suggest me how can I replace a string in a file by using scripts? That strings are contain few special characters(example: > < /> “ ”  ).

My searchString is as mentioned below

```
launcher.properties" />
```

My new string will be as mentioned below

```
launcher.properties" >     <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" /> </File>
```

when I am using below script getting error

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "search=launcher.properties" />"
set "replace=launcher.properties" > <Permission User="Everyone"    
GenericAll="yes" /> </File> "
echo replaceing hte string....2222
set "textfile=home.wxs"
set "newfile=home_t2.wxs"
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>"%newfile%"
del %textfile%
rename %newfile%  %textfile%
```

Getting below error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
< was unexpected at this time.
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

For such complicated replacements I would use more complicated script.
You can try [replacer.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/replacer.bat)  (the `e?` before the file name is for evaluation of unicode sequences - quotes in this case )

```
call replacer.bat e?home.wxs "launcher.properties\u0022/>" "launcher.properties\u0022 > <Permission User=\u0022Everyone\u0022  GenericAll=\u0022yes\u0022/> </File>"
```

it is a jscript/bat hybrid and should be saved with `.bat` extension (you can use it on any windows system without prerequisites).

you can check also [FindRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) and [JRepl](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) which are more sophisticated tools

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. When I use replacer.bat file I am getting below error replacer.bat(68, 3) ADODB.Stream: File could not be opened.

Comment: @mallikgm is the home.wxs in the same directory?Generally this means that the script cannot find the file

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is caused by the (initial) `set` commands and the way the command line interpreter (CLI) parses double-quotes, because there are double-quotes within the values. The CLI usually takes the second double-quote to end the portion opened by the first double-quote, the fourth closes the third, and so on. For everything in between each found pair of double-quotes `""` special characters like separators, redirections, pipes (`&`, `<>`, `|`) are not detected, but they are recognised outside of such pairs.
Supposing there are no said special characters in between double-quoted strings in your input file (for example, `"Everyone"` or `"yes"` like in the `%replace%` string), the following code should work:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "search=launcher.properties"" />"
set "replace=launcher.properties"" > <Permission User=""Everyone""    GenericAll=""yes"" /> </File> "
echo replacing hte string....2222
set "textfile=home.wxs"
set "newfile=home_t2.wxs"
(for /F "delims=" %%I in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%I"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:"=""!"
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    set "line=!line:""="!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
)) > "%newfile%"
del /P "%textfile%"
rename "%newfile%" "%textfile%"
```

What I'm doing here is giving two consecutive double-quotes instead of each one in your `search` and `replace` values, and also in each read line from the original file `%textfile%`, and replace them by a single `"` *after* the search-and-replace operations. In between the `%%` or `!!` for variable expansion/substitution, double-quotes seem to have no more special meaning.

**Note:** For checking the final values of `search` and `replace`, you cannot use `echo` because you fall into the same problem like described on top. Instead, type `set search` or `set replace` to display the respective values.

Comment: I added the `/P` switch to the `del` command to halt the script for user prompt, so you can check the contents of the output file `%newfile%` prior to deletion.